# Pytest won't run any tests

Tags: python, pip, pytest, pep8

I couldn't get pytest to run tests on Python 3.6, so I uninstalled and reinstalled Python 3.7. Then I downloaded pytest and pep8 using pip and added

C:\Users\CoolT\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Scripts

to PATH. Now I can't get pytest to run anything.

`py.test` and `python` command prompt commands are not working and when I try to run a test, this is what happens:

```html
C:\Users\coolt\mymodules>py -3 -m pytest vsearch.py
C:\Users\coolt\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pep8.py:110: FutureWarning: Possible nested set at position 1
  EXTRANEOUS_WHITESPACE_REGEX = re.compile(r'[[({] | []}),;:]')
================================================= test session starts =================================================
platform win32 -- Python 3.7.2, pytest-4.1.1, py-1.7.0, pluggy-0.8.1
rootdir: C:\Users\coolt\mymodules, inifile:
plugins: pep8-1.0.6
collected 0 items

============================================ no tests ran in 0.18 seconds =============================================
```

Any ideas of how to fix my issues?

Comment: Did you follow the [naming conventions](https://pytest.readthedocs.io/en/latest/goodpractices.html#conventions-for-python-test-discovery) for tests in pytest?

Comment: What is the naming convention?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get a test to run by asking it to make a pep8 check. I ran this as an administrator in command prompt:

```html
py -3 -m pytest --pep8 vsearch.py
```